# Like as a preposition and prepositional phrase sub categorization rules

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, lexicon

I'm trying to figure out how the sentence "My hands are shaking like crazy," breaks down into lexical categories. I know "like" can function as a preposition, meaning "similar to", but I'm not sure if "like" can be a preposition since I don't think "crazy" is a noun/object in this sentence, and from what I know, PP's require noun phrases as a sub-categorization rule in syntax.

I would say "crazy" is an adverb since it seems to be modifying "shaking", but that leaves me clueless as to how like functions in the sentence.

Please explain the different parts of speech for "like" and "crazy" in this sentence.

Thank you!

Comment: So interesting.  *(I love informal English and all forms of dialect!)*

Comment: Taken collectively, ***like crazy*** is an "intensifier". I wondered what the full OED would make of the similar (BrE?) expression [like billyo](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/like-billyo), so I looked it up. Intriguingly, OED says ***billyo*** is a "noun", but I really can't imagine what kind of "thing" it refers to (it virtually never occurs except in that "compound intensifier" context).

Comment: Actually, I'd say ***crazy*** in your context is an adjective (short for *like crazy **hands*** - i.e. shaking the way that crazy hands would shake). But how that parsing would work with ***billyo*** is beyond me.

Comment: In your example, "like" is a preposition. The informal "like crazy" is a comparative expression, more specifically a manner adjunct, cf. "My hands are shaking in a crazy manner".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Well it's a noun intensifier, as in 'working like stink'.

Comment: _Like crazy_ is an idiomatic fixed phrase, and therefore its parts no longer have individual lexical categories because they've been reified. It's pointless to argue how to label non-terminal nodes; you can have as many angels dancing on them as you like.

Comment: ... Crystallised into a single lexeme.

Comment: I agree that it's idiomatic. But it can still be analysed as a preposition phrase functioning as a manner adjunct. And it's not a single lexeme!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you are probably familiar with shaking hands, aren't you? :P

Comment: Kaitlyn you are right it's functioning like an adverb modifying shaking. It's very similar to saying: "My hands are crazily shaking" or "My hands are shaking crazily". "Like" works to intensify the meaning and tell us your hands are shaking "so" crazily, but as an idiomatic style to intensify meaning. In informal English "like" can work as a conjunction or adverb - in this sense it's kind of similar to replacing "like" with "so".

Comment: Colloquially, notice how any adverb (but not intensifier) formed from adjective + 'ly' can be replaced by adjective + ' like', and often this 'like' can be fronted on the adjective.

Answer (score 2):

**Like crazy** is an idiom and should be treated as a single word; an adverb describing how my hands were shaking.

Answer (score 0):

Prepositions can sometimes take adjectives as complements; see the following question: ["Far from happy" Preposition followed by an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473453/far-from-happy-preposition-followed-by-an-adjective)

I would say that "like" has the same function here as it does when followed by a noun phrase in a sentence like "My hands were shaking like the dickens" or "My hands were shaking like hell".

*Like* can be classified as a preposition (as you mention): historically, it's derived from an adjective, and "traditional" grammarians categorized it as an adjective when it modified a noun and as an adverb when it modified a verb. Whatever you call it, I would say that *crazy* functions as the complement of *like* in this sentence. But as John Lawler said in a comment, "like crazy" is established as a fixed expression.

I don't think that you can necessarily use any adjective in this position. A similar example I thought of is "like mad". Using the Google Ngram Viewer, I found that some people use "like wild", although it is less common:

> There he was, running like wild, chasing after us.

([*Contagious* and *Deathly Contagious*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wAYKBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT63&dq=%22running%20like%20wild%22), by Emily Goodwin, Chapter 12)