# "Far from happy" Preposition followed by an adjective?

Tags: prepositions, complements

It occurs me that in such sentences as

> He is **far from happy**.
>
> However, just as the critics are not of one mind in their criticism, so they are **far from united** on what to do.

the preposition **from** is followed by adjectives. Since prepositions by definition are placed before nouns/noun phrases, I wonder if **far from** is a unique case. Are there other similar cases? I can't think of any.

Is this simply an omission of **being**? Does this omission occur with other prepositions?

Comment: I know of no definition of [*preposition*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preposition) that says they must be placed before nouns or noun phrases. (Unless you are talking about the myth that you can't end a sentence with a preposition.) Where have you read such a statement?

Comment: @JasonBassford No, I am not talking about P-stranding. That's a totally separate issue. ["Prepositions show direction, location, or time, or introduce an object. They are usually followed by an object—a noun, noun phrase, or pronoun."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preposition) And it is my goal for this question to learn more about the exceptions to that *usually*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I probably should've included this in my question, but an explanation of why **from** here is an adverb and its function in those sentence would make a great answer as well.

Comment: Prepositions can take a wide range of complements in addition to NPs, including predicatives. In this case the AdjPs "happy" and "united on what to do" are predicative in that they relate to the predicands "he" and "they". Compare also "I took him for dead"

Comment: @BillJ Very helpful. So is it safe to assume "from" is a preposition here?

Comment: Yes, it is a preposition. Not a physical source location prep of course, so probably best analysed as a grammaticised one, i.e. it serves to mark a certain grammatical function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many similar constructions in English, where a preposition doesn't take a noun object: "[take for](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_for) [granted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_for_granted)", "[next to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/next_to) useless", "[close to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close_to) perfect".